# how do I take input in the date time format?

Tags: python, list, datetime, input, types

I have written a code which take `start_date` and `end_date` from user but it is throwing an error.
Following is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
start_date = datetime.strptime(input('Enter Start date in the format m/d/y'), '%m/%d/%Y')
end_date = datetime.strptime(input('Enter End date in the format m/d/y'), '%m/%d/%Y')
dates=['4/6/2013', '5/4/2013', '6/26/2013', '7/26/2013', '9/5/2013', '10/7/2013', '10/12/2013', '4/12/2014', '5/10/2014', '6/12/2014', '7/19/2014', '8/15/2014', '9/17/2014', '4/21/2015', '5/28/2015', '6/26/2015']

# this line creates a list of datetime objects from the given strings in list dates  

dt_dates = [datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y') for date in dates]

in_between_dates = []
for d in dt_dates:
    if d >= start_date and d <= end_date:
        in_between_dates.append(d)

print [d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') for d in in_between_dates]
```

and the error pops up after giving `1/1/2014` as input is as follows:

```
Enter Start date in the format m/d/y1/1/2014
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ayush\Desktop\UWW Data Examples\new csvs\temp.py", line 9, in <module>
    start_date = datetime.strptime(input('Enter Start date in the format m/d/y'), '%m/%d/%Y')
TypeError: must be string, not int
```

Comment: Could you reduce the example to [make it as small as possible](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `print` statement, seems like you are using Python 2.x .

In Python 2.x , `input()` actually evaluates the result and returns, so, if you are entering something like `1/1/2014` or some number, you would get an integer (which in this case is 1 divided by 1 divided by 2014 -> `0` ), not a string. And it is generally dangerous to use `input()` , since user can input anything and that would get evaluated.

Use `raw_input()` instead, to get the string, example -

```
start_date = datetime.strptime(raw_input('Enter Start date in the format m/d/y'), '%m/%d/%Y')
end_date = datetime.strptime(raw_input('Enter End date in the format m/d/y'), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

In Python 3.x , raw_input() from Python 2 was renamed to `input()` , so using `input()` in python 3 is same as using `raw_input()` in Python 2.x .

Answer (score 1):

For Python 2 use `raw_input` instead of `input`. For Python 3 `input` is fine.