# Taking time as input in Python

Tags: python

I mean hour and minutes. Taking them as arguments to input() function and assigning it to a variable. Is it possible?

Like this way:

```
time = input(current time)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python)

Comment: Is your intention to get the current time or to put the time in the input display or to get the time when a user inputs a response or...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387596/how-do-i-take-input-in-the-date-time-format

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need hour and minutes separately

```
from datetime import datetime
a=datetime.now()
print(a.hour,a.minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

`intput` only returns objects of type `str` (string).

However, you can be inventive by specifying a certain format and performing the conversion using `datetime` from the standard library:

```
from datetime import time

time = input('Enter a time in the format HH:MM \n')
# input 15:25

h, m = map(int, time.split(':'))
res = time(hour=h, minute=m)

print(res)

15:25:00
```