# getting 2 different date input from user

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to get user input for 2 different dates which i will pass on to another function.

```
def twodifferentdates():
    print("Data between 2 different dates")
    start_date = datetime.strptime(input('Enter Start Date in m/d/y format'), '%m&d&Y')
    end_date = datetime.strptime(input('Enter end date in m/d/y format'), '%m&d&Y')
    print(start_date)

twodifferentdates()
```

I have tried a lot of different ways to enter the dates but i keep getting

> ValueError: time data '01/11/1987' does not match format '%m&d&Y'

I have used the same code which was discussed in:
[how do I take input in the date time format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387596/how-do-i-take-input-in-the-date-time-format)

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: That is because the format is `%m/%d/%Y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `%m&d&Y` with `%m/%d/%Y` as described in the referenced post.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.strptime()` requires you to specify the format, on a character-by-character basis, of the date you want to input. For the string `'01/11/1987'` you'd do

```
    datetime.strptime(..., '%m/%d/%Y')
```

where `%m` is "two-digit month", `%d` is "two-digit day" and `%Y` is "four-digit year" (as opposed to two-digit year `%y`. These values are separated by slashes.

See also [the `datetime` documentation which describes how to use `strptime` and `strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: the changes still give me the same error: Changed code is as follows


start_date = datetime.strptime(input('Enter Start Date in m/d/y format'), '%m/&d/&Y')
    end_date = datetime.strptime(input('Enter end date in m/d/y format'), '%m/&d/&Y')

Comment: `%` and `&` are not the same character. You're using `&` when you should be using `%`. In particular, `&` does not mean anything to `datetime`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very experienced with the datetime module, but the error seems to be the way you're taking input. You should be taking it like this:

```
start_date = datetime.strptime(input('Enter Start Date in m/d/y format'), '%m &d &Y')
```

or

```
start_date = datetime.strptime(input('Enter Start Date in m/d/y format'), '%m/&d/&Y')
```